# Need to write a file to either Dropbox or Google Drive with CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, google-drive-api, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm working with the latest version of CakePHP (2.3.8) and would like to be able to write a file to either Dropbox or Google Drive.

I've been trying to get Shama's CakeBox (https://github.com/shama/cakebox) to work but it seems buggy and not well documented. The OAuth sequence doesn't want to work at all and consequently I can't get the access tokens.

Has anyone else had any luck with this component?  And if not, does anyone know of any suitable replacements?

(I know I could debug Cakebox but I'm working on a client's project and don't have the luxury of the time needed to do it.)

Comment: There is working code and instructions at: https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-php and cakephp plugin at: https://github.com/LubosRemplik/CakePHP-Google-API-Plugin if you consider Google Drive.

Answer (score 0):

There is [no adapter yet](https://github.com/KnpLabs/Gaufrette/issues/90) for [Gaufrette](https://github.com/KnpLabs/Gaufrette), but I don't think it should be hard to write one given the fact there is a SDK available.

I think the best would be to use Gaufrette, you've already got a ton of adapters besides Google Drive (Dropbox is supported), you could contribute the adapter to it and have the same interface to all storage systems. Gaufrette is well done I can recommend it, you get 75% of the work by using it and just have to finish the adapter for Google Drive that you would have to implement anyway. So why not contribute to it?

[I've written a plugin](https://github.com/burzum/FileStorage) to wrap Gaufrette in a CakePHPish way and have it used so far with Local, S3 and Rackspace.